# Inconsistent speed with simultaneous FTP downloads from same server

Tags: networking, centos, ftp, vps

I have a hosted VPS running CentOS and PureFTPd. When I try to download from multiple FTP accounts on the server **simultaneously**, I get wildly different speeds for each of the FTP connections: some are downloading at 5 MB/s, while others as low as 50 KB/s.

The downloads are being performed from the same computer running Fetch (Mac FTP client). This computer is hooked up to a Verizon FiOS connection with plenty of bandwidth. Furthermore, ping time to the server is only 10ms and traceroute shows no issues.

Since I'm not an FTP expert, does this sound like an issue with (a) the hosting company and it possibly throttling simultaneous connections from the same IP, (b) some provider in between, (c) the PureFTPd or CentOS configuration, (d) something else?

Our previous host did not have this issue, so I'm leaning towards (a), but having a hard time getting anything other than canned responses from the hosting company.

Any ideas to help me narrow down the problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue most likely lies within the I/O subsystem on the VPS (I.E., slow shared spinning disks).

Comment: The VPS supposedly has SSDs, but the host just told me that they throttle I/O. Does it sound right that I wouldn't be able to have more than two concurrent downloads? Or is this host just terrible? It's not an inexpensive amount thay I am paying.

Comment: It does make sense, keep in mind that you're not the sole user. Also, take a look at http://serverbear.com/benchmarks/vps/io